# Getting Moodle Data as JSON

Tags: php, moodle

I want to get all moodle data from courses to quizzes to streaming links all as JSON.

I followed the API documentation, got the token, but after that where and how to use this token?

For instance if I want to get the courses list, then how can I do that? If someone can share some example please.

Comment: What type of web service are you using? REST, Soap or xmlrpc?

Answer (score 3):

Step 1 : Activate webservices in moodle. Here are the steps : http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Creating_a_web_service_client

`http://<your_domain>/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=<your_token>&wsfunction=<your_function_name>`

To return the response as json you can add `&moodlewsrestformat=json`

`http://<your_domain>/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=<your_token>&wsfunction=<your_function_name>&moodlewsrestformat=json`

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : Activate webservices in moodle. Here are the steps : http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Creating_a_web_service_client

Step 2 : Read up the API documentation. This is available in Site administration->plugins->web services->API documentation. This is available only to admin users. Eg the task you want is get courses list, the correct API for this would be "core_course_get_courses". API documentation has details of all available functions.

Comment: Step3: You need to create a token in order to be able to access the web service. Go to _Site administration->plugins->web services->Manage tokens_ for that. You can then directly test the web service function from within your browser by firing: _http://<your_domain>/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=<your_token>&wsfunction=<your_function_name>_